# Entity Framework SaveChanges(False) fails while using TransactionScope

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope, savechanges

The question asked on following link has a great answer under that as well but my problem starts after that.

[Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges/815660#815660)

I tried  the code given as per my requirement as follows

---

```
MyEntities context1 = new MyEntities();

...
...
 // some code for changing the table data in Context 1.
...

MyEntities context1 = new MyEntities();

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    context1.SaveChanges(false);   // LABEL 1
    context2.SaveChanges(false);   // LABEL 2
    scope.Complete();             // LABEL 3
    context1.AcceptAllChanges();  // LABEL 4
    context2.AcceptAllChanges();  // LABEL 5
}
```

---

Things works fine till line marked with // LABEL 1
However on line // LABEL 2 it fails saying 
"The underlying provider failed on Open."

NOTE : - Please note that Context1, Context2 are 2 different instance of same Type.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: The first step to debug anything is to look at the full error message. Look at the inner exception(s).

Answer (score 0):

This answer might explain the cause of your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081776/655625
you might need to reopen the connection after the `context1.SaveChanges(false);` line.
Such as with:

```
context2.Database.Connection.Open(); //before the second SaveChanges(false)
```

However, read carefully and you will find that you're doing a distributed transaction that way, this other answer (linked from the first one) shows an alternative (more elaborate) to avoid the distributed transaction.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/794785/655625