# EF6 Database First transactions and multiple contexts

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert, transactionscope

Following the advice in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework) I'm trying to optimize a save (insert only) operation that handles several thousand records by splitting the save operation into batches of X records. Naturally, I want these operations to be part of a single transaction.

We are using an **EF6 Database First** model.

MSDN has an article about [transactions in EF6 and onwards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) that describes opening a connection and starting the transaction yourself, passing the connection to the `DbContext` constructor and calling `UseTransaction` afterwards.

However, this doesn't seem to work with Database First - it keeps invoking `DbContext.OnModelCreating` which in turn throws an `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`.

Even without transactions it doesn't work. Example:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (var context = new BloggingContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false))
{
  context.Blogs.Add(blog); // invokes ModelCreating and fails.
  context.SaveChanges(); // never gets this far
}
```

The exception actually suggests providing an `EntityConnection` instead, so I tried the following:

```
using (var sourceContext = new BloggingContext())
{
  using (var anotherContext = new BloggingContext(
    sourceContext.Database.Connection, // supply existing EntityConnection
    contextOwnsConnection: false))
  {
    context.Blogs.Add(blog); // still fails.
    context.SaveChanges(); // never gets this far
  }
}
```

Using `TransactionScope` is another option, but unfortunately this will inevitably escalate to MSDTC since multiple connections are opened, and this is not an option.

**Here's a simplified version of my attempt at optimizing the operation. How do I get the contexts that are newed up for each batch to be included in a single transaction using Database First?**

```
foreach (List<Blog> blogBatch in blogBatches)
{
  using (var context = new BloggingContext())
  {
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    context.Blogs.AddRange(blogBatch);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

EDIT: Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937587/sharing-a-connection-and-a-transaction-in-ef-across-multiple-contexts-unintenti) that seems to deal with the same issue, although still without a useful answer.