# How can i enable Transaction my codes with linqto SQL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql

if writing below codes: Error returns.i do like advise :
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794364/how-do-i-use-transactionscope-in-c 
But only error change:**The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025**

i am using windows server 2003.

```
 using (var stockMovementCtx = new StockMovementCtxDataContext())
            {
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {

// do something....
}
scope.Complete();
}
```

but if i changed my codes ; every thing is ok:

```
using (var stockMovementCtx = new StockMovementCtxDataContext())
            {


// do something....

}
```

How can i solve below error. This is really important.Please help me:((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataContext` by default wraps all operations within a `Transaction`, so you don't need to explicitly do Transaction while working with DataContext. Read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx).

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx

```
using (var stockMovementCtx = new StockMovementCtxDataContext())
{
     // do something....


     //everything until this point is within the transaction.
     stockMovementCtx.SubmitChange();
}
```

> Why we need TransactionScope ?

TransactionScope enables you to perform transactions beyond dataabse. Say you have series of operations as below and all are atomic and they need be performed within a transaction.

1.) Add record in Table 1
2.) Add record in Table 2
3.) Write a NEW file on the Disk
4.) Rename file X on the disk
5.) Update file record in Table 3

If you use SqlTransaction then only the operaration 1,3 and 5 can participate in the transaction but 3 and 4 cannot because they do not relate database at all. In such cases TrasanctionScope can help you. TransactionScope leverages the MSDTC (Distributed Trasanction co-coordinator) that can help you do transactions beyond database context. You can wrap all five operations within a TransactionScope transaction execute them atomically. It is also worth noting that TransactionScope supports nested transactions, that means one block of transaction can contain multiple set of transactions.

Comment: Dear this. __curious_geek; why we need "TransactionScope". Every thing is ok without "TransactionScope"...

Answer (score 3):

`TransactionScope` will elevate to DTC if necessary. It sounds like DTC is not correctly configured, usually due to firewall restrictions. Try a [dtcping](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306843) between the servers (important: in **both** directions).