# Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled

Tags: asp.net, system.transactions

error:

***Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.***

```
using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())   
11                 {   
12                     try  
13                     {   
14                         foreach (DataRow row in this.dt1.Rows)   
15                         {   
16                             int titleId = int.Parse(row["titleId"].ToString());   
17                             string fname = row["fname"].ToString();   
18                             string lname = row["lname"].ToString();   
19   
20                             if (cmd.Parameters.Count > 0)   
21                                 cmd.Parameters.Clear();   
22   
23                             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titleId", titleId);   
24                             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);   
25                             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);   
26                             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
27   
28                         }   
29                         con.Close();   
30                         ts.Complete();   
31                     }   
32                     catch (Exception ex)   
33                     {   
34   
35                     }                       
36                 }   
37             }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794364/how-do-i-use-transactionscope-in-c

Comment: Why use DTC if is local transaction ?

Comment: wow 6 yrs ago!, in addition to this if you are using async u need to add the "TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled" as in  

using (var trans = new TransactionScope((TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)))

Answer (score 70):

To enable Network access to **MSDTC** on **Windows Vista/7/8 Server 2008R2/2012**, follow the steps below:

1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **dcomcnfg** and then click **OK** to open **Component Services**.
2. In the console tree, click to expand **Component Services**, click to expand **Computers**, click to expand **My Computer**, click to expand **Distributed Transaction Coordinator** and then click **Local DTC**.
3. Right click **Local DTC** and click **Properties** to display the **Local DTC Properties** dialog box.
4. Click the **Security** tab.
5. Check mark **"Network DTC Access"** checkbox.
6. Finally check mark **"Allow Inbound"** and **"Allow Outbound"** checkboxes.
7. Click **Apply**, **OK**.
8. A message will pop up about **restarting** the service.
9. Click **OK** and That's all.

Comment: what are the security risks of this?  I'd rather not blindly open up network access without fully understanding what it means.

Comment: Hello Any body help me after doing this settings we receive another error

'Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed.'

Inner Exception
The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers

Comment: @EeNiArT Not sure if you have been able to solve the issue but MSDTC errors are pretty hard to know with the little information above. Can you share more details about systems involved? If you have already solved it, please share the solution.

Comment: @Sundeep addressing the MSDTC errors when migrating databases to AWS RDS can be a challenging task. In our case, AWS RDS doesn't support MSDTC transactions, which prompted us to take steps to ensure the smooth operation of our database. To resolve this, we are actively working on removing MSDTC transactions from our codebase. While we're in the process of doing this, we've made considerable progress, but the issue isn't fully resolved yet.

Answer (score 3):

Close the connection after the transaction scope Complete method.

```
ts.Complete();
con.Close();
```

the completed code is

```
using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope ts = new  Sytem.Transactions.TransactionScope())   
{   
    try  
    {   
        foreach (DataRow row in this.dt1.Rows)   
        {   
            int titleId = int.Parse(row["titleId"].ToString());   
            string fname = row["fname"].ToString();   
            string lname = row["lname"].ToString();   

            if (cmd.Parameters.Count > 0)   
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();   

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titleId", titleId);   
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);   
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);   
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
        }   
        ts.Complete(); 
        con.Close();     
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)   
    {   
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `Enlist=false;` at the end of the connection string helped me!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking at this, and using linq, then just wrap the whole transaction into a JoinScope like this:

```
using js = new JoinScope(false) {
    using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope ts = new Sytem.Transactions.TransactionScope()) { 
        ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

InnerException = {"Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool."}

I followed the below steps to resolve above issue on my local system

Enable Network DTC Access :

1. Run dcomcnfg in start to open the Component Services Administrative tool
2. Click on Local DTC and open the property window
3. Click on security Tab and make below security settings to enable Network DTC Access

   Enabled Firewall Rules related to Distributed Transaction Coordinator (TCP-IN/TPC-

For more details @https://rajeevdotnet.blogspot.com/2018/10/wcf-exception-network-access-for.html